# How can we convert a .tif with .tfw .htm into a raster KML/KMZ file to open in google earth?

Tags: geotiff-tiff, kmz, matlab-mapping-toolbox

How can we convert a .tif with .tfw .htm into a raster KML/KMZ file to open in google earth? I have a .tif file along with a .tfw and .htm files. I wanted to open it in Google Earth. Converting the .tif into a raster in KML/KMZ format will solve the problem. I was working in MATLAB mapping toolbox and did not find a solution in there. A Matlab or any opensource solution will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can load tiff files into Google Earth and embed in a kml/kmz file.

> You can open GIS imagery files to project images embedded with display
>   information over specific map coordinates in the 3D viewer. **Files
>   using NAD83 projection are not supported by Google Earth.**
>
> **TIFF (.tif), including GeoTiff and compressed TIFF file**s National
>   Imagery Transmission Format (.ntf) Erdas Imagine Images (.img) Other
>   image files You can also import images if you manually edit their
>   coordinates for correct positioning. Imagery files without the correct
>   projection information will not be accurately re-projected.
>
> Portable Network Graphic (.png) Joint Photographic Expert (.jpg)
>   Atlantis MFF Raster (.hdr) PCIDSK Database File (.pix) Portable Pixmap
>   Format (.pnm) Device Independent Bitmap (.bmp)

https://support.google.com/earth/answer/176685?hl=en

Answer (score 1):

Use GDAL2TILES.py or GDAL2TILES_Parallel.py or GDAL2TILES

Make a folder of TILES (JPG) and KML or Zip that and rename to KMZ.
I recommend using one of these Tools that are free and open source.

https://gitlab.com/GitLabRGI/erdc/geopackage-python

https://github.com/roblabs/gdal2tilesp

They will also build XYZ and TMS 256x256 TILES for use in Web and Mobile Apps.
You can also package the data into SQLite Database (MBTILES or GPKG -GeoPackage)